# fireEvent.Blur() is not working in my custom input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, next.js, react-testing-library

```
// Custom Input component

const Container = styled.div``;

const InputBase = styled.div<{ width: string }>`
  display: flex;
  width: ${(props) => props.width};
  height: 42px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid 2px ${color.gray[200]};
  background-color: white;

  &[data-focus="true"] {
    border: solid 2px ${color.gray[300]};
  }

  &[data-disabled="true"] {
    background-color: ${color.background.original};
  }
`;

const InputArea = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  &:disabled {
    color: ${color.gray[600]};
  }
  ::placeholder {
    color: ${color.gray[600]};
  }
`;

const Label = styled.label`
  color: ${color.gray[600]};
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

const Input: ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLInputElement, Props> = (
  { formWidth = "100%", icon = null, labelText, onFocus, onBlur, ...props },
  ref
) => {
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handelFocus = (e) => {
    setIsFocus(true);

    if (onFocus) onFocus(e);
  };

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    setIsFocus(false);

    if (onBlur) onBlur(e);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      {labelText && <Label htmlFor={props.id}>{labelText}</Label>}
      <InputBase
        data-focus={isFocus}
        data-disabled={props.disabled}
        width={formWidth}
      >
        <InputArea
          ref={ref}
          type="text"
          {...props}
          onFocus={handelFocus}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
        {icon}
      </InputBase>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default forwardRef(Input);
```

I'm making the component into a library and using it in another project.
The code below works normally when testing in the library.

```
describe("Input", () => {
  it("test", async () => {
    const handleBlur = jest.fn();
   
    render(
      <Input data-testid="input" onBlur={handleBlur} />
    );

    const input = screen.getByTestId("input") as HTMLInputElement;

    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "test" } });
    fireEvent.blur(input);

    expect(handleBlur).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

However, in other projects that use that library, `fireEvent.blur(input)` does not work (toHaveBeenCalledTime is 0) and `fireEvent.focusOut(input)` does.

Is there something wrong with the library bundling process? Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind expect in `async` block as-

```
      await(async () => { 
        expect(handleBlur).toHaveBeenCalled() // OR
        expect(handleBlur).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
      })
```

I did something as below which worked for me-
*Stack*- React Testing Library, React
*Requirement*- Show Error message on blur(*focus out*)

```
it('focus move out from input', async () => {
      let container: HTMLElement
      const input = container.getElementsByClassName('some-input-class')[0]

      await(async () => {
        expect(handleBlur).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })

      fireEvent.blur(input)
      const errorMsg = screen.getByText('This field is required.')

      expect(errorMsg).toBeInTheDocument()
 ]})
```